# GLIBC version not found when executing AppImage on different distro

Tags: c, linux, gcc, libraries

I'm currently working on an application that I would like to publish to many distributions. So far, I've done all my testing on one distribution at a time (compile and run on the same distro). But when I take the outputted AppImage from compilation on my main computer (Arch Linux), and try to run it in a vm (Ubuntu 20.04), it gives me the error below:

`` gabriel@gabriel-VirtualBox:~/Downloads$ ./Neptune.Installer-x86_64.AppImage  ./Neptune.Installer-x86_64.AppImage: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by ./Neptune.Installer-x86_64.AppImage) ``

What possible solutions are there to this? I've considered statically linking the library, but I'm unsure if that might cause licensing issues, as my program is not open source. Apart from that, I might consider simply compiling my program on a very old distribution such as Ubuntu 12 or something, but I won't know how well that carries over to other distros (for example, will my program still work on an old version of Fedora?)

This might be a complicated question but I just want to know what the best way to solve this issue is. Change libraries? Statically link? Compile on old distributions? Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1):

> I've considered statically linking the library, but I'm unsure if that might cause licensing issues,

Yes.

> very old distribution such as Ubuntu 12 or something, but I won't know how well that carries over to other distros

It doesn't (alpine linux). If you compile software, you have to run it with the set of libraries you compiled it against. Even if you compile on "very old distributions" there may be changes.

> publish to many distributions

Choose the list of distributions and versions of these distributions you want to support. Tell users that you will support these distribution versions. (https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/store/application/platforms -> `Steam only officially supports Ubuntu running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS or newer..`).

Compile against every combination of distribution+version separately, and distribute your software separately for every such distribution version. For users convenience, create and share package repositories for specific distribution package manager with your software. On https://www.zabbix.com/download there are only so many combinations to choose from. Interest yourself in CI/CD in docker virtualized environments. I like gitlab.

Or alternatively distribute your application with all dependent shared libraries. Bundle it all together with the operating system and distribute in a form of a docker image or a qemu/virtualbox virtual image. Or distribute with just shared libraries files with a wrapper around `LD_PRELOAD`. Just like steam does. Install steam on your system, and see what happens in `~/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_64`.

And hire a layer to solve the licensing issues.